# Does sleep mode affect parallel core simulations with R?

Tags: r, hibernate, parallel-processing

I have been successfully running some moderate sized lasso simulations in R (5k*5k*100 tables). And I was able to run all 8 threads of an i7 by breaking 100 target regressions into 13 lists of 5k*5k*8 tables each. I noticed when I ran one standalone simulation, it would take about eight minutes per simulation of 1 table, but when I ran a loop over several (size 8 tasks), it would take hours (11 hours all night) to complete.

I finally decided to write out the data in tasks of equal size proportions to a csv file as they were processed. The first few took about 8min each as expected, but when I came back home, there was a single task still running for two hours. I had thought it could be due to the data (each data table has identical regressors but different targets). But then I realized it might be due to the computer going to sleep mode. As soon as I awakened the computer, the two hour simulation quickly finished and the remaining tasks took 8min each as expected.

So does sleep (hibernate) mode, dramatically slow down overnight tasks? Is it normal, in that case, to disable hibernate until the full simulation is compete?

Build: 
intel i7 3.2G quad core
16 G ram
R Revolution 64 bit
Windows 7 Pro 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the answer is yes, hibernate does dramatically slow down R parallel simulations with a multicore computer (win7); I suspect it occurs for other (non R) overnight simulations as well.

Notice the first run had task pred.6 and pred.7 taking about 2 hours. The 2nd set of simulations (pred1.n, all had no greater than 11 minutes per sim.
The 2nd set was run with sleep/hibernate set to never in control panel power options.

[image]